# Disk Utility Constantly Crashes on Mac 10.7.1 Lion

Tags: macos

I'm running 10.7.1 server and recently have been experiencing app crashes related to hard disks.  I can't mount DMG's, can't backup with Time Machine and every single time I open Disk Utility to try and find out what's wrong, it crashes.

I've restarted, uninstalled Xcode, uninstalled VMWare Fusion, repaired disk (nothing was wrong), repaired permissions (nothing was wrong) and now I'm at a loss.  I could reinstall everything, but I can't backup what I have currently so I'm not reinstalling.

This problem seemingly came out of the blue today.  I was playing around in server this morning and was changing permissions for a share, then it crashed.  Everything after that seemed to go downhill.  Until I looked and found out that my last successful backup was like 6 days ago.  Probably coinciding with the install of VMWare fusion.  But now that it's uninstalled, I still have the problems.

Here is the log, but I'm stumped.  Any ideas?  Here's the log dump.

```
Process:         Disk Utility [721]
Path:            /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Disk Utility
Identifier:      com.apple.DiskUtility
Version:         12 (346)
Build Info:      DiskUtility-346000000000000~145
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [263]

Date/Time:       2011-08-30 02:35:12.447 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X Server 10.7.1 (11B26)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          513946 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           107
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  15 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   13
Anonymous UUID:                      9B1FD0C2-0DC5-4EEE-B956-55B0D125DC5A

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000068

VM Regions Near 0x68:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000109454000-00000001094bb000 [  412K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Disk Utility

Application Specific Information:
objc[721]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8fa16fa0 CFBundleCopyLocalizedString + 208
1   com.apple.DiskImagesFramework   0x00007fff97184db9 CBSDBackingStore::copyPropertiesDict() + 89
2   com.apple.DiskImagesFramework   0x00007fff9718473b DIInitialize + 291
3   com.apple.DiskUtility           0x0000000109456592 0x109454000 + 9618
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9019485c -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 418
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90194647 -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 303
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff901938a5 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 347
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9018a1b9 loadNib + 322
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff901896b6 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff901895d1 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90189514 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff903fc355 NSApplicationMain + 398
12  com.apple.DiskUtility           0x0000000109456499 0x109454000 + 9369
13  com.apple.DiskUtility           0x0000000109456294 0x109454000 + 8852

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eec47e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff967cf60e _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff967ce19e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eec4192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff984dd594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff984deb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eec4192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff984dd594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff984deb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000068  rbx: 0x00007ffd1ba1d460  rcx: 0x0000000000000001  rdx: 0x00000000ffffffff
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007fff7d59d8a0  rbp: 0x00007fff69053770  rsp: 0x00007fff69053700
   r8: 0x00007fff7d5bd008   r9: 0x00007fff7d59d8b0  r10: 0x0000000000000040  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x00007fff99324000  r13: 0x00007ffd1ba10ef0  r14: 0x00007fff7e7f16f8  r15: 0x0000000000000010
  rip: 0x00007fff8fa16fa0  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000068
Logical CPU: 4

Binary Images:
       0x109454000 -        0x1094bafff  com.apple.DiskUtility (12 - 346) <3E1F11CF-9628-36DE-A15D-2D48F21C1FEB> /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Disk Utility
       0x1094e0000 -        0x10954eff7  com.apple.framework.DUSupport (12 - 346) <B619A35B-2802-3B93-908A-BB259C611045> /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app/Contents/Frameworks/DUSupport.framework/Versions/A/DUSupport
       0x109598000 -        0x1095c7fff  com.apple.DiscRecordingUI (6.0 - 6000.4.1) <FBA64FAD-B209-3101-9ABD-06460CAE8F45> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecordingUI.framework/Versions/A/DiscRecordingUI
       0x1095ed000 -        0x1095effff  com.apple.RestoreFramework (1.7 - 239) <C66AED73-DC8D-317E-BBE1-6DDD9A61C253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Restore.framework/Versions/A/Restore
       0x1095fa000 -        0x10967afff  com.apple.frameworks.server.kit (10.7 - 168) <5371A777-75A8-3A28-A8E0-5A1C19FC8409> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerKit.framework/Versions/A/ServerKit
       0x1096d9000 -        0x10975cff7  com.apple.frameworks.server.foundation (10.7 - 184) <B6D7DCAD-0D14-3BA2-BCF6-BFCD900EC6C4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ServerFoundation
       0x1097c2000 -        0x1097d4ff7  com.apple.PlatformHardwareManagement (2.0.1 - 2.0.1) <B55C63E6-0117-324B-B88A-18C5003D61FC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlatformHardwareManagement.framework/Versions/A/PlatformHardwareManagement
       0x1097e5000 -        0x10981efff  com.apple.frameworks.CoreDaemon (1.0 - 1.0) <267FFC79-8640-3290-A7D7-79E4D9390AA7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDaemon.framework/Versions/B/CoreDaemon
    0x7fff69054000 -     0x7fff69088ac7  dyld (195.5 - ???) <4A6E2B28-C7A2-3528-ADB7-4076B9836041> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8d11b000 -     0x7fff8d11dfff  com.apple.EFILogin (1.0 - 1) <85E9DF63-D659-3D5E-B5DE-AE7995CF14BC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EFILogin.framework/Versions/A/EFILogin
    0x7fff8d11e000 -     0x7fff8d15dfff  com.apple.AE (527.6 - 527.6) <6F8DF9EF-3250-3B7F-8841-FCAD8E323954> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff8d15e000 -     0x7fff8d18bff7  com.apple.opencl (1.50.62 - 1.50.62) <616ADE61-11D1-3816-A255-3F0F80F2EAC8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff8d18c000 -     0x7fff8d192fff  IOSurface (??? - ???) <06FA3FDD-E6D5-391F-B60D-E98B169DAB1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff8d193000 -     0x7fff8d199fff  libGFXShared.dylib (??? - ???) <DE6987C5-81AC-3AE6-84F0-138C9636D412> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff8d19a000 -     0x7fff8d19bfff  libunc.dylib (24.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <C67B3B14-866C-314F-87FF-8025BEC2CAAC> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff8d19c000 -     0x7fff8d1f0ff7  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore (3.0 - 3.0) <C829E6A3-3EB6-3E1C-B9B8-759F56E34D3A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/Versions/A/ImageCaptureCore
    0x7fff8d1f1000 -     0x7fff8d61efff  libLAPACK.dylib (??? - ???) <4F2E1055-2207-340B-BB45-E4F16171EE0D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff8d977000 -     0x7fff8d97afff  com.apple.help (1.3.2 - 42) <AB67588E-7227-3993-927F-C9E6DAC507FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
    0x7fff8d97b000 -     0x7fff8d989fff  com.apple.NetAuth (1.0 - 3.0) <F384FFFD-70F6-3B1C-A886-F5B446E456E7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff8d98a000 -     0x7fff8d9dcff7  libGLU.dylib (??? - ???) <C3CE8BA0-470F-3BCE-B17C-A31E70E035F2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff8da05000 -     0x7fff8da5ffff  com.apple.HIServices (1.9 - ???) <8791E8AA-C034-330D-B2BA-5141154C21CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff8da60000 -     0x7fff8da8bfff  libpcre.0.dylib (1.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <7D3CDB0A-840F-3856-8F84-B4A50E66431B> /usr/lib/libpcre.0.dylib
    0x7fff8da8c000 -     0x7fff8db1efff  com.apple.CorePDF (3.0 - 3.0) <6056B710-155A-3543-9373-B9F3E5FC99CE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/Versions/A/CorePDF
    0x7fff8db25000 -     0x7fff8db26ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (53.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8BCA214A-8992-34B2-A8B9-B74DEACA1869> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8db2f000 -     0x7fff8dbc1fff  com.apple.PDFKit (2.6 - 2.6) <F838E95F-DEE9-354A-A34A-F5335D0AF1E1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PDFKit.framework/Versions/A/PDFKit
    0x7fff8dc14000 -     0x7fff8dd21fff  libJP2.dylib (??? - ???) <D8257CEE-A1C3-394A-8193-6DB7C29A15A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
    0x7fff8e05a000 -     0x7fff8e7289df  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - ???) <B3C42497-53F5-31BB-987E-D1E76746B0E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff8e729000 -     0x7fff8e734ff7  libc++abi.dylib (14.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8FF3D766-D678-36F6-84AC-423C878E6D14> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8e741000 -     0x7fff8e741fff  com.apple.Carbon (153 - 153) <895C2BF2-1666-3A59-A669-311B1F4F368B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff8e742000 -     0x7fff8e744fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (??? - ???) <2D21E6BE-CB20-3F76-8DCC-1CB0660A8A5B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x7fff8e745000 -     0x7fff8e843ff7  com.apple.QuickLookUIFramework (3.0 - 489.1) <A8A82434-D43D-3F12-9321-B2E8EC9B4B8E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/QuickLookUI
    0x7fff8e844000 -     0x7fff8ea46fff  libicucore.A.dylib (46.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <82DCB94B-3819-3CC3-BC16-2AACA7F64F8A> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8ea47000 -     0x7fff8ea51ff7  liblaunch.dylib (392.18.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <39EF04F2-7F0C-3435-B785-BF283727FFBD> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8ea52000 -     0x7fff8ed6bfff  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (960.13 - 960.13) <398ABDD7-BB95-3C05-96D2-B54243FC4745> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff8edf9000 -     0x7fff8edfdfff  libmathCommon.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FF83AFF7-42B2-306E-90AF-D539C51A4542> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff8edfe000 -     0x7fff8ee03ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (??? - ???) <4ABCEEF3-A3F9-3E06-9682-CE00F17138B7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff8ee04000 -     0x7fff8ee16ff7  libsasl2.2.dylib (3.15.0 - compatibility 3.0.0) <6245B497-784B-355C-98EF-2DC6B45BF05C> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff8ee17000 -     0x7fff8ee18fff  libdnsinfo.dylib (395.6.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <718A135F-6349-354A-85D5-430B128EFD57> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x7fff8ee19000 -     0x7fff8ee1dfff  libutil.dylib (??? - ???) <28672328-B738-38CE-B231-8A93CA6E6EA4> /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
    0x7fff8ee1e000 -     0x7fff8ee21fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib (??? - ???) <9E9F7B24-567C-3102-909C-219CF2B191FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff8ee4c000 -     0x7fff8eea8ff7  com.apple.QuickLookFramework (3.0 - 489.1) <26470DFE-B3D7-3E05-A4D7-98B64FCB230B> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/QuickLook
    0x7fff8eead000 -     0x7fff8eecdfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.22.73 - compatibility 1.0.0) <69F2F501-72D8-3B3B-8357-F4418B3E1348> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8eedc000 -     0x7fff8ef24fff  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (2.0 - 200.46) <04AFD988-DDFB-330D-B042-C1EB2826A0CC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
    0x7fff8ef25000 -     0x7fff8ef3bfff  libGL.dylib (??? - ???) <22064411-0A62-373C-828B-0AA2BA2A8D34> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff8ef45000 -     0x7fff8ef4cff7  com.apple.CommerceCore (1.0 - 17) <AA783B87-48D4-3CA6-8FF6-0316396022F4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
    0x7fff8ef4d000 -     0x7fff8efbdfff  com.apple.datadetectorscore (3.0 - 179.3) <AFFBD606-91DE-3F91-8E38-C037D9FBFA8B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
    0x7fff8f09e000 -     0x7fff8f0a3fff  libGIF.dylib (??? - ???) <21851808-BFD2-3141-8354-A419479726BF> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff8f0a4000 -     0x7fff8f0e8ff7  com.apple.MediaKit (11.0 - 585) <8F2DF50A-03D2-3551-AD92-74A9262D6B0F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaKit.framework/Versions/A/MediaKit
    0x7fff8f0e9000 -     0x7fff8f103fff  com.apple.CoreMediaAuthoring (2.0 - 889) <99D8E4C6-DDD3-3B0C-BBFB-A513877F10F6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaAuthoring.framework/Versions/A/CoreMediaAuthoring
    0x7fff8f107000 -     0x7fff8f108fff  libffi.dylib (??? - ???) <DB96CC4B-0D38-3102-80AA-91DDE9AF3886> /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
    0x7fff8f10d000 -     0x7fff8f14cff7  libGLImage.dylib (??? - ???) <29F82AD9-45F0-3AC5-A4A4-B767EC555D82> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff8f14d000 -     0x7fff8f14dfff  com.apple.CoreServices (53 - 53) <5946A0A6-393D-3087-86A0-4FFF6A305CC0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff8f1ae000 -     0x7fff8f1b2ff7  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.5 - 94) <0BB2C436-C9D5-380B-86B5-E355A7711259> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
    0x7fff8f1b3000 -     0x7fff8f1c2fff  com.apple.opengl (1.7.4 - 1.7.4) <38AF4430-7E81-3C98-9330-21DCDA90507E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff8f227000 -     0x7fff8f27afff  libFontRegistry.dylib (??? - ???) <8FE14D77-1286-3619-A02E-0AC1A622596E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff8f424000 -     0x7fff8f4beff7  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <B7573888-BAF6-333D-AB00-C0D2BF88DF0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff8f4bf000 -     0x7fff8f730fff  com.apple.CoreImage (7.77 - 1.0.1) <AB6ECCF3-4B04-3363-9158-08F305BF15FA> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
    0x7fff8f731000 -     0x7fff8f73eff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib (1.0.5 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8EDE3492-D916-37B2-A066-3E0F054411FD> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff8f73f000 -     0x7fff8f76cfe7  libSystem.B.dylib (159.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <7B4D685D-939C-3ABE-8780-77A1889E0DE9> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8f76d000 -     0x7fff8f772fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (6.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <98ECD5F6-E85C-32A5-98CD-8911230CB66A> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8f773000 -     0x7fff8f8fdff7  com.apple.QTKit (7.7.1 - 2246) <C8A57DE8-A86A-34B6-B6BA-565EE3B6D140> /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit
    0x7fff8f98f000 -     0x7fff8f9d4fff  com.apple.DiskManagement (4.1 - 501) <AEB6CA4E-DD4D-3828-B268-3EFFC104FB94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskManagement.framework/Versions/A/DiskManagement
    0x7fff8f9d5000 -     0x7fff8fba8ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.7 - 635) <57446B22-0778-3E07-9690-96AC705D57E8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff90113000 -     0x7fff9011cfff  libnotify.dylib (80.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <BD08553D-8088-38A8-8007-CF5C0B8F0404> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
    0x7fff90179000 -     0x7fff90d71fff  com.apple.AppKit (6.7 - 1138) <C8D2FDDA-B9D5-3948-A376-6B9B6F0596C6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff90d80000 -     0x7fff90d8cfff  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework (10.7 - 144) <067ACB41-E9B7-3177-9EDE-C188D9B352DC> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
    0x7fff90d8d000 -     0x7fff90dcfff7  libcommonCrypto.dylib (55010.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A5B9778E-11C3-3F61-B740-1F2114E967FB> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff90dd0000 -     0x7fff90dedfff  libPng.dylib (??? - ???) <75DA9F95-C2A1-3534-9F8B-14CFFDE2A290> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
    0x7fff91b76000 -     0x7fff91c79fff  libsqlite3.dylib (9.6.0 - compatibility 9.0.0) <ED5E84C6-646D-3B70-81D6-7AF957BEB217> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff91c7a000 -     0x7fff92095fff  com.apple.SceneKit (2.0 - 124) <9E331DDE-BDF4-34C5-A8F9-E7F12ADBB785> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SceneKit.framework/Versions/A/SceneKit
    0x7fff92096000 -     0x7fff92097fff  com.apple.ServerInformation (1.0 - 1) <EE6BFCB2-C727-3CE6-B8C9-834230B2646B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerInformation.framework/Versions/A/ServerInformation
    0x7fff92098000 -     0x7fff920d7ff7  libcups.2.dylib (2.9.0 - compatibility 2.0.0) <DE681910-3F7F-3502-9937-AB8008CD281A> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff920d8000 -     0x7fff920dafff  libquarantine.dylib (36.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <4C3BFBC7-E592-3939-B376-1C2E2D7C5389> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff92429000 -     0x7fff9242cfff  com.apple.AppleSystemInfo (1.0 - 1) <598ADC13-C994-3579-A885-0D6658DDD564> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSystemInfo.framework/Versions/A/AppleSystemInfo
    0x7fff9242d000 -     0x7fff9243fff7  libz.1.dylib (1.2.5 - compatibility 1.0.0) <30CBEF15-4978-3DED-8629-7109880A19D4> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff92440000 -     0x7fff928e7ff7  FaceCoreLight (1.4.2 - compatibility 1.0.0) <6F89E9A9-DEB6-32B5-8B50-3B97F5DB597D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/Versions/A/FaceCoreLight
    0x7fff928e8000 -     0x7fff928f3fff  com.apple.DisplayServicesFW (2.5.0 - 302.1.2) <36377733-C737-3F36-A601-85D6188A2AAA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DisplayServices.framework/Versions/A/DisplayServices
    0x7fff928f4000 -     0x7fff92908ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <04C31EF0-912A-3004-A08F-CEC27030E0B2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
   ---Shortened so I can post here---

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 384
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=177.6M resident=157.6M(89%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=20.0M(11%)
Writable regions: Total=61.1M written=2344K(4%) resident=2676K(4%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=58.5M(96%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG shared images                     96K
MALLOC                             50.7M
MALLOC guard page                    32K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              9752K
VM_ALLOCATE                          56K
__CI_BITMAP                          80K
__DATA                             17.0M
__IMAGE                            1256K
__LINKEDIT                         47.9M
__TEXT                            129.7M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        15.6M
shared memory                        16K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             328.4M

Model: MacPro5,1, BootROM MP51.007F.B03, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 2.8 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 1.39f11
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5770, ATI Radeon HD 5770, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: DIMM 1, 8 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D33393342314B37304348302D4348392020
Memory Module: DIMM 2, 8 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D33393342314B37304348302D4348392020
Memory Module: DIMM 3, 8 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D33393342314B37304348302D4348392020
Memory Module: DIMM 4, 8 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1066 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D33393342314B37304348302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.10)
Bluetooth: Version 2.5.0f17, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
PCI Card: Apple RAID Card, sppci_raid, Slot-4
PCI Card: ATI Radeon HD 5770, sppci_displaycontroller, Slot-1
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVD-RW GH61N
USB Device: Ext HDD 1021, 0x1058  (Western Digital Technologies, Inc.), 0x1021, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x5a100000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8215, 0x5a110000 / 5
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, 800mbit_speed
```

Comment: If you're familiar with terminal you can take a backup; take a look at this article it might help http://wiki.onmac.net/index.php/How_To_Backup_your_Mac

Comment: Did you by chance make any changes to your language settings recently? If so, try reverting them, or check to see if it still happens if you set them to plain old english. Just a hunch, based on the crash occurring in `CFBundleCopyLocalizedString` (a method to get a localized string from an application bundle).

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379 View that support article. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing in your Report that gives me a clue to the cause.

Whenever I have unusual behavior like this, I reboot in Safe mode, then restart normally.

Safe mode startup is a very useful fix-almost-all-OS-problems tool.  It does a Repair disk during the boot process, and is faster than booting from an external drive to run DU-Repair Disk on the internal drive.

Disk Utility is an app native to the OS.  When it or any other native app misbehaves, you should concentrate your repair efforts on the OS.  When booting in Safe mode, all 3rd party additions are "disconnected", and only the base functions of the OS are activated.

My second effort at fixing this problem would be to re-install the latest Combo update. This will do a similar thing - revert any intentional or inadvertent changes to the OS back to the default state, without affecting your data and most settings.

Third, if you have a relatively current external backup clone, you might try booting in that drive to see if the DU problem persists.  If the problem is not there, you can clone that drive to the internal drive and restore current data from Time Machine.

Those folks that are Terminal-savvy may offer better solutions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I've noticed that the reason the Disk Utility appears to "hang" is because there are a large number of images/dmg's listed in the left panel (the Most Recently Used listing).

I'm not sure why having a large number of these files causes a problem, but I have certainly seen that time machine sparse bundles (in particular) make the load time very slow.

I (unfortunately) dont know a way clear the MRU other than open DIsk Utility, right-click the item and select "Remove".

Little comfort I know, but maybe this will help someone else :)

Comment: The sidebars of many OS X programs allow dragging items out (what I like to call drag and destroy) which turns them into a puff of smoke and removes them.  You can of course select multiple items and both right click -> Remove, or drag and destroy

Answer (score 0):

Short version, could be bad RAM.

Longer version: it started in a way that made it look like a disk problem. The computer would not boot up off of the HD, and when you went into recovery mode it said the drive was not fixable. We booted off of another Lion drive and at first it seemed ok but then we started to get similar SIGSEGV crashes, first in Disk Utilities but then in other apps as well. When other apps were affected I became suspicious of the RAM so I ran the Apple Hardware test, and it said everything was ok. I was still suspicious of the RAM so I swapped it out. Since then his computer has been rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, only in my scenario, I don't use VMWare. I first noticed the problem with FCP 7.0.3 and Motion 4.0.3. Both FCP and Motion, have similar symptom as Disk Utility, i.e. they start up, crash immediately during start up, and then show a crash report with a re-open option.

However, in my situation, Disk Utility wasn't originally affected, only FCP and Motion. I was able to mount a utility (DMG) to uninstall FCP Studio and then re-install it, but it didn't fix FCP and Motion. Then on a subsequent try, Disk Utility wouldn't mount the DMG and started producing the same behavior as FCP and Motion ever since.

Below is a shortened version of the output from the Disk Utility crash (shortened due to comment post length size):

```
Process:         Disk Utility [20086]
Path:            /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Disk Utility
Identifier:      com.apple.DiskUtility
Version:         12 (346)
Build Info:      DiskUtility-346000000000000~145
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [146]

Date/Time:       2011-09-03 15:54:46.729 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.1 (11B26)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          459866 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           35
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  16 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   8
Anonymous UUID:                      51785C25-8CEF-455A-8229-F11220231605

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000068

VM Regions Near 0x68:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000103f6e000-0000000103fd5000 [  412K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Disk Utility

Application Specific Information:
objc[20086]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000104cb8fa0 CFBundleCopyLocalizedString + 208
1   com.apple.DiskImagesFramework   0x00000001040b7db9 CBSDBackingStore::copyPropertiesDict() + 89
2   com.apple.DiskImagesFramework   0x00000001040b773b DIInitialize + 291
3   com.apple.DiskUtility           0x0000000103f70592 0x103f6e000 + 9618
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001054aa85c -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 418
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001054aa647 -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 303
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001054a98a5 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 347
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001054a01b9 loadNib + 322
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010549f6b6 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010549f5d1 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010549f514 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000105712355 NSApplicationMain + 398
12  com.apple.DiskUtility           0x0000000103f70499 0x103f6e000 + 9369
13  com.apple.DiskUtility           0x0000000103f70294 0x103f6e000 + 8852

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001083177e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001080d160e _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001080d019e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000108317192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001081c6594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001081c7b85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000108317192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001081c6594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001081c7b85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000068  rbx: 0x00007fd27e86f290  rcx: 0x0000000000000001  rdx: 0x00000000ffffffff
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000104e6d8a0  rbp: 0x00007fff63b6d7b0  rsp: 0x00007fff63b6d740
   r8: 0x0000000104e8d008   r9: 0x0000000104e6d8b0  r10: 0x0000000000000040  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000104b7d000  r13: 0x00007fd27cd0c840  r14: 0x00000001041b36f8  r15: 0x0000000000000010
  rip: 0x0000000104cb8fa0  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000068
```